# HTML Table - limit <td> data overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML Table:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>The table width attribute</h1>

<table width="400">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

when i enter into  lots of data (for example: instead of 100$ i enter 1000000000000000$) it keeps spreading. i tried to limit it's width to like 10px and overflow-y auto and didnt work...

any idea how i can limit the amout of chars inside  and auto enter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer if you think it worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this.

The width you gave to your table was `400` so if you can do that then you should limit it.

there is CSS property called `overflow-wrap` this will help you to bring the extra content in that block.

```css
td {
  max-width:20px;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The table width attribute</h1>

<table width="400">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**OR**

Another option is to give a selector class to `td` and provide css property to only that class, that should also work for you.

Comment: @Manjuboyz- Thanks a lot! seems like that max-width did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` or refer to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)